# java string comparison failing

Tags: java, arrays

can u please tell why this loop is not getting executed. I'm checking two conditions here. If I check single condition it works.

```
if ((!format_values[i].toString().contentEquals("epoch") || (!format_values[i].toString().contentEquals("julian"))) && (String.valueOf(days)!="\\N" || String.valueOf(days)!="")){
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format_values[i]);
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, +Integer.valueOf(days));

                    //setting column values
                    values[column] = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
                }
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(days)!="\\N"` should use equals.

Comment: contentEquals is comparing the entire contents of format_values[I], have you looked at the content, surely you want to use a contains method?

Comment: Your conditions are also faulty. `x!=a || x!=b` is always true if `a` is not equal to `b`.

Comment: thanks .. I have done the changes recommended